# Can I install Jenkins on an unpriviledged account?

Tags: windows-xp, jenkins

I'm trying to test Jenkins and see how it would work for our project. The problem is, there are a lot of policies and restrictions about services on my work computer , and Jenkins fails to start with the message:

```
Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. A Windows
service must first be installed ...
```

Is there a possibility of running Jenkins without installing it ( maybe in a portable way )? I cannot create services, nor special user accounts for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible, since starting Jenkins is actually a prerequisite to installing it.

First, verify that you have JRE 1.5 or later. Then it should "just work" with

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

Alternatively, you could launch Jenkins through Java Web Start (test drive mode) then visit http://localhost:8080/ to configure.

If your local policies allow installing a VM host system, a longer way around would be to create a guest VM that allows you to create priviledged accounts.

Finally, if you have a servlet container that supports Servlet 2.4/JSP 2.0 or later (Glassfish, Tomcat 5, JBoss, Jetty 6) you can deploy jenkins.war like a normal WAR file.